# Using approximate solution for system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have a system:
\begin{align*}
x' &= (2y+cx)(z+1)\\
y' &= (cy-x)(z+1)\\
z' &= -z^3
\end{align*}
Solving for $z$ yields $$z = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2t+c_1}}$$
for $z(0)>0$.
I want to show that if $c<0$ every solution converges to the origin.

The question is, since $z$ approaches $0$ for t large, can I just set $z = 0$ and can go from there? Do I need to show that $x$ and $y$ are bounded first? I think $x$ and $y$ must be bounded because of the way the derivatives are set up(if x is large and postive its derivative becomes negative), but I'm not sure how to formally prove this.

Comment: Very intuitively (I have no firm ground to say that), considering an approximation in the vicinity of $\infty$ (expression you may know for saying "$t$ large") [instead of an approximation around some finite value] isn't a good approach.

Comment: @JeanMarie I know to do it formally i would need to set up limits with finite approximations. But does this way work in the end .

Comment: I imagine that your exact solution is obtained by writing the first equations under the form $x'/y' = (2y-cx)/(cy-x)=z+1.$

Comment: @JeanMarie How did you get the last equality?

Comment: Sorry, it is $ x'/(2y-cx)=y' /(cy-x)=z+1.$

Comment: In fact considering this double equation, sending $z$ to infinity and keeping for example $x'$ and $y'$ bounded means that both denominators tend to zero, thus it means you are in the vicinity of the intersection of the lines with equations $2y=cx$ and $x=cy$, i.e., in the vicinity of $(0,0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This system is exactly solvable. We need to solve:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2t+C_1}} \right)(cx+2y)$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2t+C_1}} \right)(-x+cy)$$

Let's introduce a new variable:

$$s=(1+\sqrt{2t+C_1})^2$$

$$t=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{s}-1)^2-\frac{1}{2}C_1$$

$$dt=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sqrt{s}-1}{\sqrt{s}} ds$$

Substituting into the equations, we obtain a linear system with constant coefficients:

$$\frac{dx}{ds}=\frac{1}{2}(cx+2y)$$

$$\frac{dy}{ds}=\frac{1}{2}(-x+cy)$$

The solution (by usual methods) is:

$$x(s)=e^{cs/2} \left(C_2 \cos \frac{s}{\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{2} C_3 \sin \frac{s}{\sqrt{2}} \right)$$

$$y(s)=e^{cs/2} \left(-\frac{C_2}{\sqrt{2}} \sin \frac{s}{\sqrt{2}}+C_3 \cos \frac{s}{\sqrt{2}} \right)$$

For $c<0$ it is now obvious that both solutions approach $0$ for $t \to \infty$.